# transparent issue outline of the object is still showing up

Tags: rendering, shaders, transparency, shader-nodes

I'm trying to have a smooth transparent fade but the outline of the object is still showing up.

[image]

Comment: Hello could you please pack your image and share your file?

Comment: here is the link to the file but I'm curious if it's because of the model I'm using   https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hkIW4rFDLU-gvk9XUXZVFZ2c_E9nmeb2/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

These black areas are caused by overlapping faces, it is called *Z fighting*, your topology seems rather messy, a simple <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge by Distance* doesn't seem to be enough to fix the problem, you'll probably need to rework the topology manually.